# Email bouncing when sending mail to appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have set up appengine to allow incoming mail, and if I have my web.xml file with

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>VerifyReply</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

it works and runs the VerifyReply servlet, but if I want to limit incoming emails to only those sent to the verifyreply@... email address with (notice the url-pattern is different than above)

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>VerifyReply</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mailhandler</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/v*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <url-pattern>/_ah/mail/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

it stops working and I get an email bounce back to the sender.  My logs page shows the server ran /_ah/mail/verifyreply@... but it doesn't run the servlet and bounces the email.

Any ideas, I think I am following the guide at https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving

Comment: I did more testing on this and if I put the whole email name (verifyreply@...appspot.com instead of v* then it works.  Everywhere I look v* should work, but it is not working, maybe an appengine bug?

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/receiving), filtering on address is not supported:

`When App Engine moved to a standard Java Web Server, the ability to specify richer matching patterns was lost (e.g. one used to be able to specify a url-pattern like /_ah/mail/support*). If such pattern matching is desired, consider using a filter-based approach based on the following code snippets.`

It would consider it a bug that specifying the full address does work. The page contains an example on how to do address matching in a mail handler filter (a filter in the servlet sense). You should match the address there and return a 404 if you do not want to accept the message. Or you can just ignore messages you don't want if you don't care about bouncing them.